# pg_fetch_all() prints integers as strings

Tags: php, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have

```
$result = pg_query($dbconn, 'SELECT * FROM domain');
$d = pg_fetch_all($result);
var_dump($d);
```

And the result is

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["domainname"]=>
    string(15) "stackoverflow.com"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["domainname"]=>
    string(13) "example.com"
  }
}
```

Here the problem is that the `id`s are shown as string even though they are integers. How can I get them as integers automatically?

Comment: Ok.. I saw it.. nvm.. I'll delete this one soon!! hehe xD

Comment: @FirstOne, it is integer http://imgur.com/a/r8fW9 whoever is converting it to a string doesn't matter. I like it as original type.

Comment: Show your schema?  I've never seen pg_fetch_all do this -- though it might be var_dump.  Try `print_r()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

It's up to you to manually convert the string into an appropriate numerical type, and to verify that the number represented by the string fits in that numerical type.

Even though many times the integer used internally in the database can be the same bytesize as the integer type used by php, there are too many special cases (like 64-bit database numbers coming back to a 32-bit PHP binary, etc.) for any particular automatic conversion policy to be acceptable.

More generally, PostgreSQL has `numeric` and `decimal` types that have "up to 131072 digits before the decimal point" and "up to 16383 digits after the decimal point" (see Table 8-2 [in the PostgreSQL docs]).(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: But if you use MySQL you can get integers as integers and strings as strings automatically https://jpauli.github.io/2014/07/21/php-and-mysql-communication-mysqlnd.html . There should be a way for PostgreSQL too.

Comment: Sure there is.  Just automate a way of doing it.